# Show hide element on same button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following sample [code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WWKOvE):

**CODE HTML:**

```
<ul>
  <li class="item"> item 1 </li>
  <li class="item"> item 1 </li>
  <li class="item"> item 1 </li>
  <li class="item"> item 1 </li>
  <li class="item hidden"> item 1 </li>
  <li class="item hidden"> item 1 </li>
</ul>
<button class="button">Show/Hide element</button>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

**CODE JS:**

```
$('.button').on('click', function (e) {
  var item = $('.item');
  item.removeClass('hidden'); 
});
```

I want to add class `.visible` to the elements that previously had the `.hidden` class. Basically I want to hide the items again at the next click and be a toggle of classes.

How can I hide the last two items?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `toggleClass()` http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: [`.toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `.toggle()`

```
 $('.button').on('click', function (e) {
      $('.hidden').toggle('visible'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, no need of css, just .toggle() will do it.

```js
$('.button').on('click', function (e) {
  $('.hidden').toggle(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item"> item 1 </li>
  <li class="item"> item 1 </li>
  <li class="item"> item 1 </li>
  <li class="item"> item 1 </li>
  <li class="item hidden"> item 1 </li>
  <li class="item hidden"> item 1 </li>
</ul>
<button class="button">Show/Hide element</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can also use below approach:

**CSS**

```
.hidden {
 display:none;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$('.button').on('click', function (e) {
      $('#anyElement').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use switchClass to remove existing one and add second.
[image]

Comment: if you does not set time it works like without time.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, You can loop through each element on button click and remove/add the relevant classes.

```js
$("button").click(function(){
     $("li").each(function(){
         let $this = $(this);
         if($this.hasClass('hidden')){
        $this.removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
         } else if($this.hasClass('visible')){
        $this.removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
         }
      })
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item"> item 1 </li>
  <li class="item"> item 1 </li>
  <li class="item"> item 1 </li>
  <li class="item"> item 1 </li>
  <li class="item hidden"> item 1 </li>
  <li class="item hidden"> item 1 </li>
</ul>
<button class="button">Show/Hide element</button>
```